# How can I know how much Google Cloud Platform had been charged or need from me in the billing aspects?

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform

I have an account inside GCP, and need to know exactly what GCP need from me as a charge or from my MasterCard balance so far? How can I do that as the amount it said 1.x K USD which is too high I guess.

If someone can help, this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Your billing account's [History page](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/view-history) contains details about your costs and payment information, and you can view all your transactions and sort them by transaction types or by account's payment information.

If you can't find a specific charge or transaction related to a Google Cloud Platform API, you can submit a billing ticket through the [Cloud Services Billing Requests](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing) form.

You may also use the view your cost trends with the Billing Reports. See examples and how-tos [here](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to view your GCP Transactions you can follow the steps provided [Here in the GCP Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/view-history)

The Steps are:

- Sign in to the Google Cloud Platform Console.
- Open the console left side menu and select Billing
- If you have more than one billing account, select Go to linked billing account to manage the current project's billing. To locate a different billing account, select Manage billing accounts.
- Click Transactions.

Cloud billing can quickly grow out of hand if unchecked, definitely be careful of what you provision, and for serverless services like Big Query, be very careful of how you formulate queries that have the potential to touch very large amounts of data, as they can incur significant costs.

Here is the link to the GCP Billing Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/

And here are some additional Billing related links you may find useful:

**Resolving Billing Issues**
https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/resolve-issues

**Budgets and Alerts**
https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets

**Invoiced Billing**
https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/invoiced-billing